# SQL Server performance: Composite Key with Foreign Key constraint

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

Consider a system where each `message` belongs to exactly one category, and a page which displays the message *only in a selected category*.

The `message` table will be constructed as:

```
Id (PK),
CategoryId (FK of [category]),
...
```

To show the messages, one would use `SELECT * FROM message WHERE CategoryId = 123`. Assuming this query is executed very frequently, it would be wise to construct a non-clustered index on the `CategoryId` field. Thus we have,

**Approach 1 (using pseudo SQL syntax):**

```
Id,
CategoryId,
PK is [Id],
[CategoryId] is FK of [category]
Clustered index on [Id],
Non-clustered index on [CategoryId]
```

However the chance of manipulating a message using `Id` is very small. We can order the message to be sorted according to `CategoryId` in the physical disc, saving a non-clustered index:

**Approach 2:**

```
Id,
CategoryId,
PK is [CategoryId, Id]
[CategoryId] is FK of [category]
Clustered index on [CategoryId, Id]
```

How about modifying approach 1 such that the clustered index is not created in `Id`:

**Approach 3:**

```
Id,
CategoryId,
PK is [Id],
[CategoryId] is FK of [category],
Clustered index on [CategoryId]
```

My questions are:

1. Would approach 2 or 3 benefit in performance because the query optimizer can lookup a clustered index vs non-clustered?
2. Assuming approach 2 is selected, would be benefit the query optimizer if a non-clustered index on `CategoryId` is constructed as well, thus giving it "more options"?
3. Is it true that only queries that are based on the start of a composite key benefit from such "composite key clustered index"? I.e. if the PK is [Id, CategoryId] instead, such index would be useless in a query `... WHERE CategoryId = 123`?
4. Does having a foreign key inside a composite primary key have any performance implications (be it good or bad)?

Notes:

1. I'm using SQL Server, but I expect the answer is generic to database systems.
2. I'm aware of similar questions ("FK in composite PK" and "performance of FK"), but none of them address the combination of the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clustered index is the primary sorting mechanism for you table data.  All data in the table will be sorted by the clustered index.  Tables can be either a clustered index (sorted) or a heap (non-sorted).  Without a clustered index, the table is considered a heap.

Second, indexes are sorted from left-to-right, based on the column ordering in the index.  In approach 2, CategoryId will be searched first, and then Id would be searched.  If only Id is supplied in the where clause, the index can still be used, but it will be a complete index scan at best.

If your messages will always be accessed using a combination of categoryid and id, approach 2 will work well.  However, if your messages are ever accessed using only id (including updates and deletes), and id is the second field in your index, the index will likely not be used.  This is because a index is considered a "tree", where the left-most values are at the root of the tree, and the right columns are the "branches".  You have to start at the root and work your way out.

As far as clustered vs. non-clustered, both will perform similarly.  The only difference being the clustered index actually sorts all of the data in the table.

In Summary:

1. Yes
2. Likely, yes.
3. Yes, though not completely useless. An index scan can still be better than a table scan (also called a clustered index scan).
4. No.

Comment: "As far as clustered vs. non-clustered, both will perform similarly." : if the page display a lot of messages at a time (say 20 or 50), then clustered index will benefit, because it is a sequential read of the physical file vs random access using non-clustered, correct?

Comment: The clustered index will be faster because the related data is on the same page as the clustered index, so you avoid a "lookup".  An additional lookup will have a very small impact on 20 or 50 records.  However, if your number of records increased, to the thousands, a bookmark lookup can be expensive, so the clustered index would performance faster.

Answer (score 1):

The performance of the optimizer isn't your only consideration. Generally speaking, you want your clustering key to be small, monotone increasing, and unique. Your CategoryId suggestion satisfies smallness, but will likely be random (thus not monotone) and definitely not unique. Monotonicity is important to avoid physical fragmentation. Uniqueness is a little trickier to explain, but it comes down to the engine needing to be able to uniquely identify the row. If your key isn't unique, the engine will add a uniquifier to the row, thus making the row larger.